# Delete regex matches within loop and continue with updated string version

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string that I want to run through four wordlists, one with four-grams, one with tri-grams, one with bigrams and one with single terms. To avoid that a word of the single term wordlist gets counted twice when it also forms part of a bigram or trigrams for example, I start with counting for four-grams, then want to update the string in terms of removing the matches to only check the remaining part of the string for matches of trigrams, bigrams and single terms, respectively. I have used the following code and illustrate it here just starting with fourgrams and then trigrams:

```
financial_trigrams_count=0
financial_fourgrams_count=0

strn="thank you, john, and good morning, everyone. with me today is tim, our chief financial officer."

pattern_fourgrams=["value to the business", "car and truck sales"]
pattern_trigrams=["cash flow statement", "chief financial officer"]

for i in pattern_fourgrams:
    financial_fourgrams_count=financial_fourgrams_count+strn.count(i)

new_strn=strn
def clean_text1(pattern_fourgrams, new_strn):
    for r in pattern_fourgrams:
        new_strn = re.sub(r, '', new_strn)
    return new_strn

for i in pattern_trigrams:
    financial_trigrams_count=financial_trigrams_count+new_strn.count(i)

new_strn1=new_strn
def clean_text2(pattern_trigrams, new_strn1):
    for r in pattern_trigrams:
        new_strn1 = re.sub(r, '', new_strn1)
    return new_strn1

print(financial_fourgrams_count)
print(financial_trigrams_count)
word_count_wostop=len(strn.split())
print(word_count_wostop)
```

For fourgrams there is not match, so new_strn will be similar to strn. However, there is one match with trigrams ("chief financial officer"), however, I do not succees in deleteing the match from new_strn1. Instead, I again yield the full string, namely strn (or new_strn which is the same).

Could someone help me find the mistake here?

Comment: Do you know the 2 functions you define are never called?

Answer (score 1):

(As a complement to Tilak Putta's answer)

Note that you are searching the string twice: once when counting the occurrences of the ngrams with `.count()` and once more when you remove the matches using `re.sub()`.

You can increase performance by counting **and** removing at the same time.

This can be done using `re.subn`. This function takes the same parameters as `re.sub` but returns a tuple containing the cleaned string as well as the number of matches.

Example:

```
for i in pattern_fourgrams:
    new_strn, n = re.subn(r, '', new_strn)
    financial_fourgrams_count += n
```

Note that this assumes the n-grams are pairwaise different (for fixed n), i.e. they shouldn't have a common word, since `subn` will delete that word the firs time it sees it and thus won't be able to find occurence of other ngrams containing that particular word.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove `def`

```
import re
financial_trigrams_count=0
financial_fourgrams_count=0

strn="thank you, john, and good morning, everyone. with me today is tim, our chief financial officer."

pattern_fourgrams=["value to the business", "car and truck sales"]
pattern_trigrams=["cash flow statement", "chief financial officer"]

for i in pattern_fourgrams:
    financial_fourgrams_count=financial_fourgrams_count+strn.count(i)

new_strn=strn
for r in pattern_fourgrams:
    new_strn = re.sub(r, '', new_strn)

for i in pattern_trigrams:
    financial_trigrams_count=financial_trigrams_count+new_strn.count(i)

new_strn1=new_strn
for r in pattern_trigrams:
    new_strn1 = re.sub(r, '', new_strn1)

print(new_strn1)
print(financial_fourgrams_count)
print(financial_trigrams_count)
word_count_wostop=len(strn.split())
print(word_count_wostop)
```